# How to figure out files that have been renamed?

Tags: c#, file-io, polling

How can i detect if a file has been renamed?

I am using a Poll method and not the System File Watcher method.

Currently I can detect changes with the System.IO.File object via the LastWriteTime property (DateModifed in File Explorer). However, when the file is renamed, I cannot see any property such as date properties changing date.

How can I detect file renames using a poll method?

*The funny thing is that the directory that the file resides in changes date on renaming a file.*

Comment: Why would you not want to use FileSystemWatcher?

Comment: @astander This is probably not the case for Valamas, but in my case I needed to monitor files on a network drive; and I can't remember but either the event never fired or it behaved inconsistently.

Comment: FSW is notorious for being not 100% accurate. Many use the polling method with the FSW. We are going to build the whole system with the notion that if the software is off, that polling should resume where it had left off. We may add FSW in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do this at one stage with a small group of files, in that case, I stored the filepaths of every file, as well as create-date and filesize every time I polled.

Then every subsequent poll, I was able to detect files that are now 'missing' from the last time I polled. Then, I would cross check time created and filesize to detect if some of the newer files match some of the missing files. If I get a match, I assume a rename.

Please note however, it may not be safe / 100% accurate; you may have multiple files with the same create date and filesize etc. In my case, it was use generated photographs, I was able to also check exif data as a final verification. Depending on your situation, you may have other pieces of data to verify against.

Comment: this had crossed our minds. So we will now set out to create a hidden index file and also add to that the MD5 hash to use as a reference.